# which text writing classes are the most efficient for writing lots of small files?

Tags: c#

I have to write 300+ files to a server share on a hourly basis. A quick implementation using CreateText takes approximately 1.4 seconds per file. I know there is a better way to do this, but I am unsure *which* way is actually the quickest/most efficient; hence my question:

**Which text writing class is the most efficient for writing hundreds of small files ( 336 bytes on average ) to a server share?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [File.WriteAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx).Lesson is, let C# do it in its own way because implementers must have cared about the performance.

I tried benchmarking two functions with following code(Please feel free to suggest if you have better code):-

```
class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int _max = 1000000;
            string data = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
            string path="First\\" + "txt";
            string path2 = "Second\\" + "txt";
            var s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 336; i++)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(path+i, data);
            }
            s1.Stop();

            var s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 336; i++)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path2+i))
                {                   
                        sw.WriteLine(data);                    
                }
            }
            s2.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Loop1 {0}\n",((double)(s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000) / _max).ToString("0.00 ns"));
            Console.WriteLine("Loop2 {0}\n", ((double)(s2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000) / _max).ToString("0.00 ns"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

---

> And I got following output:-

[image: Output]

For a file count of `3360` output was:-

```
Loop1 16880.90 

Loop2 17285.55
```

Comment: What method would you use that would not overwrite an already existing file (it shouldn't occur, but theoretically its possible)

Comment: @RobertH:- Streamwriters an expert overwriter :) , However what do you say now.??

Comment: Before doing the write, check to see if the file already exists, and if it does then break the tie by distinguishing the filename in whichever way is appropriate.  Use File.Exists(filename).

Comment: @Anonymous I am puzzled why your benchmark provided only marginal improvement of WriteAllText over StreamWriter.Write.  My benchmark showed significant improvement.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a StreamWriter for this will be fine. What you're probably best off doing though is doing many of them in parallel and letting the OS handle writing the whole lot out in the most efficient fashion.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned use parralel programming/threading - Basically if you have 400 loops and 4 cores it will do 100 loops on each core etc. quick and efficient I would think.

```
  //File name and list of string content
  var fileAndContent = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
  Parallel.ForEach(fileContent, currentFile => { File.WriteAllLines(currentFile.Key, currentFile.Value); });
```

See below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720

Within the parinthesis you can put your logic for handling each file. Add to the dictionairy your file paths and string content - then handle inside the parinthesis your logic for saving files, either way you can do what you need using paralel programming and handle validation for already saved files within the parinthesis after the lambada expression comment if you don't understand anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I did an experiment in which I wrote out some arbitrary lorem ipsum text of length 1700 bytes 300 times to 300 different text files (you know, file1.txt, file2.txt, etc), using a StreamWriter.Write and File.WriteAllText.  It took 251 milliseconds using StreamWriter and 161 milliseconds with WriteAllText.

Here's the basic code I used:

```
string filename = @"c:\zfile";
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int x = 0; x < 300; x++)
{
    string newfn = filename + x.ToString() + ".txt";

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newfn);
    writer.Write(text);
    writer.Close();
}
sw.Stop();
long em = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

Console.Write(em.ToString());
```

For File.WriteAllText, replace the StreamWriter code with:

```
File.WriteAllText(newfn, text);
```

I don't know what this *CreateText* thing is you write about, but it seems slow.